# How to change dbpath location of mongodb on Windows 10?

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb 4.2 on my Windows 10 PC. It is installed in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2. It seems the `dbpath` which is the database location is by default at `data` folder. I would like to change `dbpath` to `C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\mongodb_data`. How can this be done on Windows 10? The information found on the net are for linux machines.

Comment: Simply change it and restart the service. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the data directory path on startup.. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory

This means the following should work:
`mongod --dbpath C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\mongodb_data\`

Comment: I notice there's a file mongod.conf for windows 10. What's the difference between modifying `dbPath` variable in this config file versus your method of running mongod comand?

Comment: if i understand this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/ correct, the config file is to make it easier to change a lot of parameters:

_"Using a configuration file makes managing mongod and mongos options easier, especially for large-scale deployments."_